# Maven Artifact.getFile() returns NULLin a multi module project

Tags: maven, plugins, dependencies

I am developing a Maven plugin in a multi module project, what I want to use later in the same project. This is the project's layout:

```
sk:a:1.0:pom
   |
   --sk:a0:1.0:jar (the custom plugin)
   |
   --sk:a1:1.0:pom
   |  |
   |  --sk:a11:1.0:jar (a simple JAVA jar)
   |  |
   |  --sk:a12:1.0:jar (a simple JAVA jar)
   |
   sk:a2:1.0:pom
```

The sk:a2:1.0 has a dependencies on sk:a11:1.0 and on sk:a12:1.0 and the plugin sk:a0:1.0:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>sk</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>a2</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sk</groupId>
      <artifactId>a11</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sk</groupId>
      <artifactId>a12</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>sk</groupId>
        <artifactId>a0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
        ...
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The custom plugin from sk:a0:1.0 in its execute() calls the

```java
Set<Artifact> artifacts = project.getDependencyArtifacts();
```

method and iterates on all the artifacts, with:

```java
for(Iterator<Artifact> iterator = artifacts.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
   Artifact artifact = iterator.next();
   getLog().info((artifact.getFile() == null ? "artifact NULL" : "artifact OK"));
}
```

and now it displays "artifact NULL". In my plugin I need to able to read the artifact's files (like a java.io.File). How could I get the File for each dependency?

Thank you,

SK

Comment: Can you describe what you like to achieve with the plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that Maven has not yet resolved all of the project's dependencies, at the point at which your mojo is being executed.

So for example if your mojo runs in the `compile` phase, then maven has not yet resolved the `test` dependencies (those marked with test in your pom), and for all of these `test` artifacts no file will be available yet.

You can use the `@requiresDependencyResolution <required-classpath>` mojo javadoc tag, to tell maven to resolve the required dependencies.

From the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html) it states the following about this annotation:

> Flags this Mojo as requiring the dependencies in the specified class path to be resolved before it can execute.

So in your Mojo you can simply add the following annotation in your mojo's javadoc:

```
/**
 * @goal your-goal
 * @requiresDependencyResolution test
 */
public class YourMojo extends AbstractMojo
```

This basically will tell maven to resolve all dependencies that would be included in the `test` classpath (which is basically all dependencies). So your `artifact.getFile()` call should now always return a File.